# CAKEPHP MYSQL ORDER ISSUE

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I meet with a problem, and I don't know how to solve it.
I have a table, `orders`
Our client wants to only display orders that not 'approved' .
First, I thought it was easy, using `find('order_status!='=>'approved' )`...
it display database error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order IN ('12', NULL, '', NULL, '08/22/2012', 'Yes', 'No', NULL, ' \r\n  test da' at line 1

After failed many times.(removed all associated tables, checking syntax, write sql in phpadmin)

I thought the problem is Order is a reserved-word and Cakephp will automatically set alien as order.

So I used query $this->Order->query("SELECT * FROM orders where order_status = 'approved';"); 
I got another error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders'
>   in 'where clause'

Actually, CakePHP still do the same thing, "...FROM `orders` AS `Order...`"

from url : /orders?order_status=approved, it works, but I do not know how to express '!=approved'

How to fix it? I don't want to rename orders table.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
$this->Order->find('all', array(
   'conditions'=>array(
     'NOT'=>array('Orders.order_status'=>'approved')
   )
));
```

Also you should use integer 1 or 0 for this type of stuff rather then strings, easier to use in ifs. Like 1 for approved 0 (default) for unapproved.

Comment: i used your method, but still got error. I will change approve to 1, pending to 2, try again, thanks.

Comment: $results = $this->Order->find('all', array('conditions'=>array( 'NOT'=>array('Order.id'=>19)
   ))); still not work, I think the problem is 'order' Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: I asked my teacher, if has any solution, I will post it. Also I need help....I hope it can be solved today.....

Comment: use $this->element('sql_debug'); maybe on your layout, show me your output so I can tell you where is your mysql wrong. Also you should have in app/Config/core.php debug set to 2 for the mysql dump to show

Answer (score 0):

This is from my teacher, and it works.

```
$this->set('orders', $this->paginate('Order', array("Order.order_status !=" => 'Approved')));
```

and I still don't know why it doesn't work, when first get the array using find(all,condition) , then assign it to paginate...